# Concatenating fields with label expressions using Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, labeling

I am trying to combine three numeric fields together for a feature's label. I only want to label the feature if it is over 0. The labeled numbers need to be separated a dash ("-"). This is what I attempted to use as the label expression in ArcMap 10.2:

```
def FindLabel ( [a1], [a2], [a3] ):
    if ([a3]) == 0 and int([a2]) == 0 and ([a1]) == 0:
        label = " "
    elif ([a3]) == 0 and int([a2]) == 0
        label = [a1]
    elif ([a3]) == 0
        label = [a1] + "-" + [a2]
    else:
        label = [a1] + "-" + [a2] + "-" + [a3]
    return label
```

Comment: What errors or issues did you have?

Comment: I get this when I try to verify the expression or hit OK: "Error 0 on line 0. SyntaxError: invalid syntax(<string>, line 4)."

Comment: What are the field types for a1, a2, a3, and are there Null values for any?

Comment: All three field types are String and there are some null values.

Comment: You're missing the colon on the end of the elif expressions, that would be why it's not working. For example change *elif ([a3]) == 0 and int([a2]) == 0* to *elif ([a3]) == 0 and int([a2]) == 0:* for correct syntax. If you have null values the expression is *[A3] == None* for null.

Answer (score 4):

This function doesn't need to be too complex. Convert the items you want into a list, then join the result.

```
def FindLabel([A1], [A2], [A3]):
    args = [A1, A2, A3]
    items = [str(x) for x in args if bool(x) and int(x) > 0]
    if any(items):
        return '-'.join(items)
    else:
        return ' '
```

If this were proper Python, you would normally use `*args` to accept any number of arguments into a list.

Comment: That's not how an ArcGis label expression works MikeT, have a read of this http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000027000000 that functionallity *will* work if you supply that as another sub and call it from the find_label sub - that name is special, but if you name it join_label and call it from find_label it works great!

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson OK, I see how it works.

Comment: Awesome! Great expression for its simplicity and diversity: '_'.join, ' '.join etc.. works just as well. I like the use of any(items), that's not one I've seen before, usually I do *if len(items) != 0* but that can mean a list of empty items. Thanks for that, I'll be using it in the future.

Comment: +1 for a nice pythonic approach that isn't limited to only 3 fields with set names.

Answer (score 3):

There are missing semi-colons and problems with the parentheses. then you should make sure that you always have a string output.

EDIT : sorry, I've given a solution for the field calculator. This solution is updted for the labelling engin.

```
def FindLabel ( [A1], [A2], [A3] ):
    a1=[A1]
    a2=[A2]
    a3=[A3]
    if ( (int(a1) == 0) and (int(a2) == 0) and (int(a3) == 0)):
        label = " "
    elif ( (int(a2) == 0) and (int(a3) == 0):
        label = str(a1)
    elif (int(a3) == 0):
        label = a1 + "-" + a2
    else:
        label = a1 + "-" + a2 + "-" + a3
    return label
```

note that the following test are equivalent

```
 int(a1) == 0
```

and

```
 a1='0'
```

for testing if a field is null, you can use

```
 if not a1:
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm (very) new to Python. My fields are all Strings. I tried the code you wrote, as well as the following (since my fields are Strings). Neither worked and I get the same error. 
`
    def FindLabel ( a1, a2, a3 ):
    if ( (int(a3) == 0) and (int(a2) == 0) and (int(a1) == 0)):
        label = " "
    elif ( (int(a3) == 0) and (int(a2) == 0):
        label = str(a1)
    elif (int(a3) == 0):
        label = str(a1) + "-" + a2
    else:
        label = str(a1) + "-" + a2 + "-" + str(a3)
    return label
`

Comment: +1 for the edited solution for labelling. If this doesn't work I'd guess that something is wrong with the data

Comment: your first elif statement is checking a2 twice, I'm assuming you meant to check a2 and a3.

Comment: @papadoo you are right, it's a typo. Corrected by now.